# How to get the Mpart from the part's handled tool item?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to to get the Mpart from which the handle tool item belongs  when user clicks on handled toolitem of the toolbar (Here the command which will be executed on clicking  is common across these toolitems).I tried using activepart but it seems  if any other part is active in other partstack this will return wrong value .Any pointer on this will be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming this is  the toolbar in the MPart (rather than in the Trimmed Window TrimBar) `@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART)` has always worked for me.

Comment: I was trying to get part from Epartservice Now i switched to @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART)` to get the correct active part in your handler `@Execute` or `@CanExecute` methods:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart activePart)
```